# Save Cookie in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, cookies, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight Web Application and want to save user credentials if it checks "Keep me signed in" checkbox.

```
if (KeepMeSignedIn)
                    {
                        SetCookie("CECrd", userName, password);
                    }
```

The Set cookie function is as folows..

```
private static void SetCookie(string key, string uname, string password)


        {
            string cookieName = "CECrd";
            string oldCookie = HtmlPage.Document.GetProperty(cookieName) as String;
            DateTime expiration = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromDays(2000);
            string cookie = String.Format("{0}={1}={2};expires={3}",key,uname, password, expiration.ToString("R"));
            HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty(cookieName, cookie);
        }
```

But i am unable to save the cookie in the browser.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies consist of name-value *"pairs"*

### e.g.

- Name=value
- AnotherName=AnotherValue
- expires=somedate

Your string.format has a property with 2 equals signs in it!

```
string cookie = String.Format("{0}={1}={2};expires={3}",key,uname, password, expiration.ToString("R"))
```

Which generates "{key}={uname}={password};expires={somedate2000daysfromnow}" which is two entries:

- {key}={uname}={password};           // invalid
- expires={somedate2000daysfromnow}   // Valid